# How to inject dependencies into HttpSessionListener, using Spring?

Tags: spring, servlets, dependency-injection, httpsession, servlet-listeners

How to  inject dependencies into HttpSessionListener, using Spring and without calls, like `context.getBean("foo-bar")` ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since the Servlet 3.0 ServletContext has an "addListener" method, instead of adding your listener in your web.xml file you could add through code like so:

```
@Component
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener, ApplicationContextAware {

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if (applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
            ((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext).getServletContext().addListener(this);
        } else {
            //Either throw an exception or fail gracefully, up to you
            throw new RuntimeException("Must be inside a web application context");
        }
    }           
}
```

which means you can inject normally into the "MyHttpSessionListener" and with this, simply the presence of the bean in your application context will cause the listener to be registered with the container

Comment: So by this approach, can you then completely remove 'MyHttpSessionListener' from your <listener/> section from within your web.xml?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You do not even need a web.xml with this approach.

Comment: In Spring 5.x you don't need to ApplicationContextAware interface. The @component is registering the Listener just fine as it seems.

Answer (score 8):

You can declare your `HttpSessionListener` as a bean in Spring context, and register a delegation proxy as an actual listener in `web.xml`, something like this:

```
public class DelegationListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        ApplicationContext context = 
            WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
                se.getSession().getServletContext()
            );

        HttpSessionListener target = 
            context.getBean("myListener", HttpSessionListener.class);
        target.sessionCreated(se);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: That's fine solution, I wonder why there's no such DelegationListener in Spring itself.

Comment: One reason why this doesn't work as well as with DelegatingFilterProxy is that there is no way to pass it a parameter from the web.xml. You end up having to assume a bean name and then you can only ever support a single DelegationListener (unless there's a way around that I'm not seeing).

Comment: this is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

With Spring 4.0 but also works with 3, I implemented the example detailed below, listening to `ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent>` and injecting the `HttpSession` https://stackoverflow.com/a/19795352/2213375