# Detect session timeout in Spring 3/Spring Security 2.0.5

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web application running under Spring 3 with SpringSecurity 2.0.5.
To present the user the changes to the site since his last visit, I try to register the time when his session is destroyed. Therefore I registered `org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener<HttpSessionDestroyedEvent>` and also a `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`. 
The implemented methods work when the user uses the logout link. But when the session times out it's as if the events aren't generated.

Am I forgetting to listen to the right events? Or is there nothing fired for the session timeout? Is there any other way to achieve this? Does it depend on a server setting (which is tomcat 6.0.24 btw)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't do Spring, so no wording about this, but the [`javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) should work when implemented and registered properly. You need to register it as a `<listener>` in the `web.xml` as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Keep in mind that you're testing the session timeout the right way. Closing a webbrowser window for example won't *immediately* destroy the session on the server side. The session will live as long as the client hasn't sent any HTTP request for 30 minutes. Those 30 minutes are the default session timeout which is configureable by `<session-timeout>` entry in `web.xml`.

Also, the servletcontainer won't *immediately* destroy sessions after exactly the timeout value. It's a background job which runs at certain intervals (e.g. 5~15 minutes depending on load and the servletcontainer make/type). So don't be surprised when you don't see the `sessionDestroyed()` method being called after *exactly* 30 minutes of inactivity. However, when you fire a HTTP request on a timed-out-but-not-destroyed-yet session, it will be destroyed immediately.

#### See also:

- [How does Servlets, ServletContext, HttpSession, etc work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)

Comment: Seems I was to impatient and overlooked some NullpointerExceptions :D It works. Thx

Answer (score 2):

I think, DelegatingSessionListener approach may be useful. It already mentioned here:

[How to inject dependencies into HttpSessionListener, using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433321/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-httpsessionlistener-using-spring)