# Is there a "Spring 3 MVC way" to listen to the end session event?

Tags: java, spring, session, servlets, spring-mvc

I would like to delete some temporal files when user session finishes. The information associated with the files is stored in an object annotated with `@SessionAttributes`.

The only way I've found to deal with this is creating an `HttpSessionListener`.

Is there a higher level, simplified, Springy way to listen to the session end event where I could easily get my annotated object?

Comment: If the user logs out, you can act on that event.  If the user just wanders off, `HttpSessionListener` is the only option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely will need to create a HttpSessionListener.

Another stackoverflow answer:

[Detect session timeout in Spring 3/Spring Security 2.0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719691/detect-session-timeout-in-spring-3-spring-security-2-0-5)

Also and example on how to load spring beans into it:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-do-dependency-injection-in-your-session-listener/

Answer (score 6):

Two options to use `HttpSessionListener` with spring beans:

The first is to use `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredApplicationContext(servletContext)` to obtain the servlet context. From there you have two sub-options:

- use `getBean(..)`
- If you want to use `@Autowired` / `@Inject` use `getAutowireCapablyBeanFactory().autowireBean(this)`. You will have to do this only once (check if the fields are `null`), because the listener is singleton.

The second option is to use [AspectJ and `@Configurable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) on the listener.

Comment: I've been researching this topic for awhile. Do you know where I can find a complete example of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know, but I think the above snippets should be sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related, but might be an interesting project to look at.

https://github.com/shawnmclean/Idle.js

Session deletion typically happens on the server side, when the session expires (usually 30mn). The project above allows to detect user behaviors in the front end.