# Spring: Invoking a method before session timeout

Tags: spring, session, timeout

I currently have a Spring 3 project and what I want to do is retrieve my session when the session expires. I have been doing some research and apparently the `HttpSessionBindingListener` can handle this although in a Spring project, I can't seem to figure out how to implement this properly. Within my session, I save a `UserDetailsImpl` object which contains my `User` object. Should I be implementing the `HttpSessionBindingListener` on the stated objects?

To be clear, what I want to do is retrieve the user's id from the session object before it expires.

EDIT: Apparently the `HttpSessionBindingListener` does not work properly in Websphere but it is okay in Tomcat. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can also register listener in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And use method `sessionDestroyed()`

This is detailed describd in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720512/516167

Inject Spring Application Context in this Listener like is described in this question:

[How to inject dependencies into HttpSessionListener, using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433321/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-httpsessionlistener-using-spring)

Other possible solution are described here:

[Logout/Session timeout catching with spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843010/logout-session-timeout-catching-with-spring-security)