# Spring - Injecting a dependency into a ServletContextListener

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, dependency-injection

I would like to inject a dependency into a `ServletContextListener`. However, my approach is not working. I can see that Spring is calling my setter method, but later on when `contextInitialized` is called, the property is `null`.

Here is my set up:

**The ServletContextListener:**

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener{

    private String prop;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletContextListener#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Initialising listener...");
        System.out.println(prop);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }

    public void setProp(String val) {
        System.out.println("set prop to " + prop);
        prop = val;
    }
}
```

**web.xml: (this is the last listener in the file)**

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<bean id="listener" class="MyListener">
  <property name="prop" value="HELLO" />
</bean>
```

**Output:**

```
set prop to HELLO
Initialising listener...
null
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I resolved this by removing the listener bean and creating a new bean for my properties. I then used the following in my listener, to get the properties bean:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    final WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
    final Properties props = (Properties)springContext.getBean("myProps");
}
```

Comment: The way beans are instantiated make testing difficult, see my answer.

Answer (score 30):

The dogbane's answer (accepted) works but it makes testing difficult because of the way beans are instantiated. I prefere the approach suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511152/dependency-inject-servlet-listener) :

```
@Autowired private Properties props;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    WebApplicationContextUtils
        .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext())
        .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
        .autowireBean(this);

    //Do something with props
    ...
}
```

Comment: I know this is old,but for future readers, when I attempt this I get an `IllegalStateException` with the message *No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?*

Comment: Chris: I get the same problem!

Comment: @christopher @Wouter You'll have to include the Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` to fix it [as detailed in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511152/dependency-inject-servlet-listener#answer-5511255).

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned before the ServletContextListener is created by the server and so it is not managed by spring.

If you wish to be notified of the ServletContext, you can implement the interface:

```
org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why I need to implement `ServletContextAware`? My listener already has a reference to the `ServletContext` because it is present in the `ServletContextEvent`.

Comment: if you use the listener, you cannot inject spring dependencies, so the ServletContextAware is an alternative

Answer (score 1):

You cant have spring to do that, as already stated that is created by the server.
If you need to pass params to your listener, you can define it in your web xml as a context-param

```
<context-param> 
        <param-name>parameterName</param-name>
        <param-value>parameterValue</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

And in the Listener you can retrieve it like below;

```
 event.getServletContext().getInitParameter("parameterName")
```

**Edit 1:**

See the link below for another possible solution:

[How to inject dependencies into HttpSessionListener, using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433321/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-httpsessionlistener-using-spring)

Comment: I'd like to pass a bean in. Not name-values.

Comment: @dogbane see the edited post. Added a new link that may be useful for your case as well