# dependency inject servlet listener

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, stripes

In my Stripes app I define the following class:

```
MyServletListener implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener {

  private SomeService someService;

  private AnotherService anotherService;

  // remaining implementation omitted
}
```

The service layer of this app uses Spring to define and wire together some service beans in an XML file. I would like to inject the beans that implement `SomeService` and `AnotherService` into `MyServletListener`, is this possible?

Answer (score 25):

Something like this should work:

```
public class MyServletListener implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;        
    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService; 

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext())
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .autowireBean(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Your listener should be declared after Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` in `web.xml`.

Comment: @Don: `contextInitalized(ServletContextEvent)` is defined on [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent))

Comment: Important : In web.xml ContextLoaderListener must be loaded before MyServletListener.

Answer (score 12):

Little bit shorter and simpler is to use `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` class.
Than all you have to do is this:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

So using example from axtavt:

```
public class MyServletListener implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;        
    @Autowired
    private AnotherService anotherService; 

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    ...
}
```