# Make ServletContextListener spring aware

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am plugging in Spring to existing Java EE web Application. I have following lines in my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And Following `MyContextListener` class?

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
       //...
    }
}
```

What should I do to make `MyContextListener` be managed by Spring?

---

**Edited:**

My assumption is: Spring should create all servlets and all web app infrastructure so everything happened in `contextInitialized` method of `MyContextListener` should be somehow handled by Spring. How can I achieve, by implementing some interface I suppose. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to inject Spring beans into this listener?

Comment: Why do you need Spring to be aware of this listener? Can you add more info on what you need to achieve?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event

adding the ApplicationListener interface and registering a bean will let you handle the spring life cycle. 

It will be great if you can give a little more information in question on what your are trying to achieve. Let me know

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak, can we not inject Spring beans into that listener?

Comment: Only in a hacky way. I wouldn't recommend, but if you have to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746041/spring-injecting-a-dependency-into-a-servletcontextlistener

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I'm suprised of such types of questions from Spring's apologists. Why need? Just because it is a MUST for any compatible web-container. And the way spring decided to do things breaks everything and causes a lot of troubles and questuion on SO. That is why.

Comment: @AntonAstafiev first, I'm not a spring apologist. Second, there may be another problem that leads to this design, that's what I want to learn so I can provide more help; this thinking on [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). These questions were more related to understand the situation.ç

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well,

We had a similar scenario of configuring an exiting **Jersey** web services app to use **Spring** for dependency injection. Our **Jersey** webapp had extended **ContextLoaderListener** as follow

```
public class XServletContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    ... 
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        super.contextInitialized(arg0);
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        super.contextDestroyed(arg0);
        ....
    }
}
```

where *ContextLoaderListener* is

```
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
```

We included the **jersey-spring** bridge with all **spring** dependencies including **applicationContext.xml** as follow

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.*" />
    ....
    ....
</beans>
```

And obviously needed to make sure that **XServletContextListener** is included in the **web.xml** as follow

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.xxx.**.XServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Followed by *servlet* and its *init-param* values and *servlet* mapping. You can obviously adopt annotation config in place of xml confib in which case you would need to use **WebListener** annotation.

We use a variety of annotations such as

```
@Component for objects
@Service for services 
@Repository for DAOs
@Controller for controllers/resources 
@ContextConfiguration for tests
```

Everything is loaded and **autowired** by Spring framework.

Comment: why did you choose  `jersey`? OP didn't mention it

Comment: Jersey is just a web layer, nothing more (replace it with spring-mvc as you fancy and it won't affect the question asked). Anyway, this is a solution I developed for one of my projects that was using **jersey** and since I found the solution closely-related to the question being asked hence I shared it here. Just like I said, mention of *jersey* makes no difference

Comment: What about the original listeners of the application? Did you convert them into Spring beans?

Answer (score 7):

> What should I do to make `MyContextListener` be managed by Spring?

It depends on which configuration way you are using. Anyway, you should tell directly Spring to use the class you have declared. That could be done by the following way:

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener { ... }
```

A class marked with this annotation ([the Servlet 3.0 specification, 8.1.4](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1476139594_b16ed2dff1a03ae9f26c52e4fd38b494)) must implement one of these interfaces

```
HttpSessionAttributeListener
HttpSessionListener
ServletContextAttributeListener
ServletContextListener (+)
ServletRequestAttributeListener
ServletRequestListener
HttpSessionIdListener
```

that it actually does.

Personally, I prefer a meta-annotation based approach which makes my configuration shorter and more concise.

> Spring should create all servlets and all web app infrastructure so everything happened in `contextInitialized` method of `MyContextListener` should be somehow handled by Spring.

Yes, Spring will do it for you if you provide some information which could help it to register / configure / create / manage an instance.

The information may be either *meta-information* (a template that tells how to create an instance, like `BeanDefinition`s) or *a completed instance* itself (usually, it gets passed programmatically that, in turn, leads to writing a huge amount of code).

> How can I achieve, by implementing some interface I suppose.

You are implementing an interface to make your listener *a listener* (a class that describes specific methods which will be called at some points of time). Spring, itself, is responsible for guaranteeing *such calls* at *those points* of time, placing an object in the existing web infrastructure before.

Comment: If you use `@Component` instead of `@WebListener` then you can `@Autowire`as usual in this class.

Answer (score 3):

Either annotate the class with **@WebListener**  or the method with **@Bean**

Comment: In a Spring-Boot 1.3+ scenario, you need to have the package for the class annotated with WebListener annotation (and WebFilter, WebServlet annotations) fall under the ServletComponentScan annotation package scope.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate where you create a new instance of MyContextListener with `@Bean` if using Java Configs with Spring Boot.