# Callback method after ServletContext is initailized in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am running  Tomcat 9 with Sring 5.0.4 and Jdk 1.8
Need to execute code after ServletContext initialization is completed.

I have tried

> `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>`

for a servlet and tried executing my code from its init method. However, this is executed before I see the below line in logs

> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup

I have also encountered the below solution on this forum to annotate a method, but it's applicable only for spring boot.

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
```

Any pointers to an equivalent solution in spring will be really greatful

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967690/4214241) help ?

Comment: Not exactly, I am looking for an event that I can capture once Context Initialization has completed.