# Where to put Firebase listener in Java Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to accessing Firebase from my backend. My question is where I should instantiate my listeners? If I do it when one of my controller methods are called, then I loose control of the thread that is instantiated when the listener is added to the database reference. I want to keep my code as stateless as possible, so having and boolean `hasAddedFirebaseListeners` is something I would like to avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: When do you want to instantiate the listeners ? Is it during application startup ? Or when you receive a request ?

Comment: Some listeners should be instantiated during startup and some should be instantiated upon request, but most of the latter will be listening for only one single event.

Comment: why not to use ServletContextListener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746041/spring-injecting-a-dependency-into-a-servletcontextlistener