# How I can get session object from ApplicationListener method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**I want to add object to `HttpSession` after successful user authentication.** Please don't suggest solution with `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` because in this app for some reason application are ingnoring original request.

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent e) {
        //adding object to HttpSession
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I am aware, `ApplicationListener` instances are just beans within your `ApplicationContext`. Therefore you should be able to inject other beans or resources into them.

So to get a reference to the current `HttpSession` instance:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

@Autowired
private HttpSession httpSession;

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent e) {
               //adding object to HttpSession
        }
}
```

Spring will inject the `HttpSession` using its [scoped proxy mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) ensuring that you get the `HTTPSession` relevant to the current thread of execution.

You'll also need to ensure that you register a `RequestContextListener` in your web.xml so that Spring can inject the current `HTTPSession`.

```
<listener>  
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Unfortunately I'm getting `IllegalStateException`:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread?`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the registration of the RequestContextListener that should solve your problems.

Comment: I've already tested another solution. Instead of using RequestContextListener you can also change scope by adding @Scope("request") or editing bean attribute.

Comment: Surprisingly, none of the above works, still getting "No thread-bound". No other ideas? Thanks

Comment: But seems AuthenticationSuccessListener is singleton, and seems  httpSession could cause misbehaviour in multy user enviroment.