# Session-scoped bean not instantiated

Tags: java, spring, session, servlets

I want to create a session-scoped bean to monitor activations and passivations of HTTP sessions. The bean is very simple:

```
package my.log;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionActivationListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SessionLoggingListenerBean implements HttpSessionActivationListener {
    private final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public SessionLoggingListenerBean() {
        LOG.info("SessionLoggingListenerBean starting");
    }

    public void init() {
        LOG.info("SessionLoggingListenerBean init");
    }

    public void sessionDidActivate(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        LOG.info("Session " + event.getSession().getId() + " activated");
    }

    public void sessionWillPassivate(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        LOG.info("Session " + event.getSession().getId() + " will passivate");
    }
}
```

Bean definition in application context:

```
 <bean id="sessionLoggingListenerBean" class="my.log.SessionLoggingListenerBean" scope="session" init-method="init" lazy-init="false"/>
```

With this configuration there is no logs from this class, even from the constructor or init() method. Apparently, Spring does not create this bean.
By trial and error I checked that Spring instantiates such a bean when it is needed by another bean, e.g. used by UI. Is there any other (better) way? Is it a bug in Spring?
Spring version used: 2.0.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I think it is better not to use Spring for this purpose. I've modified the class to implement also HttpSessionListener and Serializable:

```
public class SessionLoggingListener implements HttpSessionListener,
    HttpSessionActivationListener, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -763785365219658010L;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SessionLoggingListener.class);

public SessionLoggingListener() {
    LOG.info("SessionLoggingListener created");
}

public void sessionDidActivate(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    LOG.info("Session " + event.getSession().getId() + " activated");
}

public void sessionWillPassivate(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    LOG.info("Session " + event.getSession().getId() + " will passivate");
}

public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    final HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    LOG.info("Session " + session.getId() + " created. MaxInactiveInterval: " + session.getMaxInactiveInterval() + " s");
    session.setAttribute(this.getClass().getName(), this);
}

public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    LOG.info("Session " + event.getSession().getId() + " destroyed");
    event.getSession().removeAttribute(this.getClass().getName());
}

}
```

and added it to web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        evo.log.SessionLoggingListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

From now on, whenever a new session is created, the listener binds to it (`session.setAttribute(...)`). This is necessary to make the container notice the listener about session activation or passivation.

---

In case of Spring and sessions - according to this [forum thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/21293-when-is-session-scope-bean-created) Spring does not load session beans until they are requested:

> Session bean is treated as a special form of "prototype". That means it will follow prototype symantics in creating an instance.

For me this is an unintuitive and not well documented behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpSessionActivationListener` is part of the `javax.servlet.http` package. That should give you a hint that it should be managed by the `Servlet` container. In your case, you aren't registering the `Listener` with your `ServletContext`, neither through the `web.xml` or a `SerlvetContainerInitializer`.

Through `web.xml` you wouldn't be able to make it both a Spring and Servlet container managed object so instead these workarounds exist, [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433321/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-httpsessionlistener-using-spring), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746041/spring-injecting-a-dependency-into-a-servletcontextlistener).

If you are using a `WebApplicationInitializer`, you can instantiate your `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`, have the `SessionLoggingListenerBean` bean created, retrieve it and use it with

```
SessionLoggingListenerBean yourBean = context.getBean(SessionLoggingListenerBean.class);
servletContext.addListener(yourBean);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I cannot use WebApplicationInitializer since my Spring is too old. I'll try other options.