# How to get Spring globalsession scoped bean in HttpSessionListener (sessionDestroyed method)

Tags: java, spring

All.
I looked through web but didn't find applicable solution for me.

I need to access information, from globalsession  scoped beans in `HttpSessionListener` , before the session is destroyed.

I found one solution, after inspecting session attributes, but it doesn't seems smooth:

```
MyBean myBean = httpSessionEvent.getSession().getAttribute("scopedTarget."+"myBeanImlp");
```

I also have singleton beans, containing session beans via target+proxy, but getting them in `sessionDestroyed`   via `ctx.getBean("mySingletonBean")`, the reference to session bean is invalid inside them (session bean was already destroyed before `sessionDestroyed`  call)

Does anybody know good and proper solution for such problem?

I'm thinking we need something like `DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor`, but for session beans, where I could look through beans, ready for destroy and take an action I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define your session listener as a component and inject ApplicationContext (or required bean) and then access it. You can take a look at [How to inject dependencies into HttpSessionListener, using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433321/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-httpsessionlistener-using-spring)