# Spring dependency not getting embedded in HTTPSessionListener

Tags: spring-security

I want to inject spring dependency in my custom HTTPSessionListener instance by following below link.If I remove the entry from web.xml sessionDestroyed method does not get called however when the entry is there in web.xml method gets called but the dependency of XUSerMgr is null.

[How to inject dependencies into HttpSessionListener, using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433321/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-httpsessionlistener-using-sp)`enter code here`ring

```
@Component
public class RangerHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener,ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    XUserMgr xUserMgr;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if (applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
            ((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext).getServletContext().addListener(this);
        } else {
            //Either throw an exception or fail gracefully, up to you
            throw new RuntimeException("Must be inside a web application context");
        }
    }

    private static CopyOnWriteArrayList<HttpSession> listOfSession = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<HttpSession>();

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        listOfSession.add(event.getSession());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        if (!listOfSession.isEmpty()) {
            updateIsActiveStatusForAuthSession(event.getSession());
            listOfSession.remove(event.getSession());
        }
    }

    private void updateIsActiveStatusForAuthSession(HttpSession session) {
        xUserMgr.updateIsActiveStatusOfLoggedInUserWithHTTPSession(session.getId(),1);
    }

    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<HttpSession> getActiveSessionOnServer() {
        return listOfSession;
    }

}
```

I have the followingentry in my web.xml. `> <listener> <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class> </listener> <listener> <listener-class>org.apache.ranger.security.listener.RangerHttpSessionListener</listener-class> </listener>`

Comment: I have the below entry in my web.xml.

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
 <listener-class>org.apache.ranger.security.listener.RangerHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

Comment: sessionDestroyed method is getting called now but the dependency is not available,it is null.

XUserMgr xUserMgr;